# Why is Foundation topbar not responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

They aren't on the actual Zurb site actually, not fully.

If you go here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html ans scroll to Built-in components you'll see my problem. It's not responsive component on a computer screen at all. Its fine on mobile (on a Nexus 4 anyway) and on a Nexus 7 in portrait mode, but even in landscape on a Nexus 7 it's all wrong.

This my code. I need 3 dropdown lists for my three sections of content and was hoping to have them side by side. I'd have it all in one list but (unlike with Bootstrap) there are not list dividers for dropdowns in Foundation.

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
    </li>
     <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Right Button Dropdown 1</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Right Button Dropdown 2</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Right Button Dropdown 3</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Left Nav Section -->
    <ul class="left">
      <li><a href="#">Left Nav Button</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the [visibility classes](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html) you can create separate `nav` for each size. It's the "official" way(look at the docs page source)

Comment: That means I have to have a different layout on each screen type. I only want the 2 - the normal full size and the automatically minimized one where the normal one doesn't fit. By your logic I'll have to specify the minimized one on certain screen sizes. How do I do that?

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect Create 2 navs. One `<nav class="top-bar show-for-large-up" data-topbar>` and another `<nav class="tab-bar hide-for-large-up">`